# Nhibernate not returning updated values

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm working on an ASP.NET application which uses Nhibernate and encountering very strange behaviour recently.

I have patient->patientAddress mapping in my Biz object. A patient can have more than 1 address but within the patient table we have a mailingAddress column which points to a row in Patint_Mailing table. my mapping file is like this.

```
 <many-to-one name="mailingAddress" 
            column="mailingAddress"
            class="DataLoad.Biz.PatientAddress, DataLoadBiz" />
```

I'm generating a csv file with patient information and I would expect this file to include all the patients and their mailing address. This works absolutely fine sometimes but sometimes it's not.

For an example if Patient A has AddressA and AddressB. We select AddressB to be the mailing address within the application. If I compile this and run I get the csv file with Patient A with AddressB. Now if I go into SQL and delete the patient A and recreate the Patient A with the same setup I will get a csv file with Patient A with Address A even though in the database it says Patient A has the mailing address Address B

Any thought why this strage behaviour?

This is my Patient mapping file

```
    <many-to-one name="practice"
            column="practice"
            class="DataLoad.Biz.Practice, DataLoadBiz" />

    <many-to-one name="mailingAddress" 
            column="mailingAddress"
            class="DataLoad.Biz.PatientAddress, DataLoadBiz" />

    <bag name="addresses" lazy="false" >
        <key column="patient"/>
        <one-to-many class="DataLoad.Biz.PatientAddress, DataLoadBiz"/>
    </bag>

    <bag name="mailings" table="MAILING_PATIENT">
        <key column="patient"></key>
        <many-to-many column="mailing" class="DataLoad.Biz.Mailing, DataLoadBiz" />
    </bag>
```

and this is the PatientAddress mapping file

```
    <many-to-one name="patient" 
        column="patient" 
        class="DataLoad.Biz.Patient, DataLoadBiz" />
```

Once I update the patient details with the correct mailing address I can go to the database and see that it's properly updated. So there's no issue in there. but when nhibernate reading those values back from the DB it's seems to ignore the fact that I updated the mailingaddraeess

I have a web form with Original Address fields and Mailing Address fields. User can copy the Original Address across to Mailing Address and when they click the Next button I call the AddAddress() method in my patient class

```
    public virtual void AddAddress(ref PatientAddress Address)
    {
        Address.patient = this;
        this.addresses.Add(Address);
    }
```

and in my Dao object I call the Save method

```
patientAddressDao.Save(updatedAddress);
```

then I updating the patient object's mailing address with the correct updated address

```
patient.mailingAddress = updatedAddress;
```

Comment: Can you post full Patient/address xml mapping and update code?

Answer (score 1):

If you save Patient class ensure your Patient class have Cascade="All" or "all-delete-orphan" in address collection mapping.

When you say "We select AddressB to be the mailing address" are you setting a flag in Address class?

**update**

If you save Patient class use also inverse="true" in Patient class on address collection mapping if you have a bidirectional mapping.

**update**

the code you provide just add a new address but doesn't "select" it. You just have a list of two address refers to one patient. Where do you mark the address as mailaddress?

**update**

```
 <many-to-one cascade="all" inverse="true" name="mailingAddress" 
    column="mailingAddress"
    class="DataLoad.Biz.PatientAddress, DataLoadBiz" />
```

and

```
patientDao.SaveOrUpdate(patient);
```

Comment: In a different page we setting the AddressA as the mailing address of the patient. So in Patient table's mailingAddress column will get updated with the Id from the Patient_address table

Comment: If I understand your situation you need a Patient class with a list of address with a property like "MainMailAddress". All addresses needs to have always a PatientId to bind it. In the other page I think you need only to set this new property "MainMailAddress" and save the patient.
Post more xml mapping to help us on helping you! :)

Comment: Preety much. yeah. BUt the set up works fine with the update to the database bit. So when I update my patient A with AddressB it updates.  But the problem is when I read the DB for updated values so I can write them to a csv file , the patient still points to the AddressA even though the patient mailingAddress column has the Id of AddressB

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to save the selected address?

Comment: I've updated my original question with more code. This is very strage or I'm doing something wrong here

Comment: cascade='all' doesn't seems to do any difference :(

Comment: that didn't help me sort the problem out mate :(

Comment: Try posting your full update method code or try to log generated SQL.

Comment: I was stepping through the code and notice that even though we change the mailing address in differnt web page the process of generating the csv file still get hold to the original address the patient been assigned to.  In the database everything looks absolutelly fine though. mailing address has been properly setup but to make my life a missery it's getting wrong data out from no where.